# Using variables as part of a variable reference

Tags: c++

Pretty simple c++ question here, how do I replace part of variable reference with another variable, almost to concatenate it.

For example I have a structure with `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, I ask the user what Item they want the information of which is stored in a variable `itemNo` for example:

```
cout << "The item you selected is " << item(itemNo).name;
```

if `itemNo==1` the reference would need to become `item1.name`;

Brackets is wrong in this scenario, but what is the right way to insert a number to form the right variable reference?

Comment: You want to learn arrays.

Comment: You can't do this, but you don't need to. Just use an array instead of 3 separate variables.

Comment: *Brackets is wrong in this scenario*, not if you overload `operator()`. But whether that is the right thing to do or not depends on the context (though it seems unlikely). Probably you need a vector or a map.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, if you name member `item1`,`item2`, `item3`,etc then you rather want a `std::array`, or if the number of items is dynamic then `std::vector`. Once you use a container as member, the container does provide a means of element access. However, as you are asking for it, it follows a way to make `items(itemNo).name` work. It makes use of operator overloading. And it uses a vector to store the data.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Item { std::string name = "name";};
struct Items {
    std::vector<Item> data = std::vector<Item>(10);
    Item& operator()(size_t i) { return data[i];}
    const Item& operator()(size_t i) const { return data[i];}
};

int main() {
    Items items;
    items(5).name = "Hallo";
    std::cout << items(0).name << " " << items(5).name;
}
```

For further reading I refer you to [operators@cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) and [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading). For the containers [container@cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), and [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score -1):

You can define struct as a holder for your item

```cpp
struct item {
   std::string name;
}
```

and then you can store items in array.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct item {
   std::string name;
};

int main() {
  std::array<item, 3> items{ {{.name = "item1"}, {.name = "item2"}, {.name = "item3"}}};
  item& current_item = items[0];
  std::size_t  chosen{0};
  std::cout << "choose item (1-3):\n";
  std::cin >> chosen;
  current_item = items[chosen];

  std::cout <<  "current item: " << current_item.name << "\n";
}
```

You can switch to `std::vector` if you want to store dynamic number of elements.